# Angular @Input not working on browser back and component won't render

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

On parent component, I have a product list that I get from store:

```js
// ...
ngOnInit() {
  this.products$.subscribe(products => {
     this.products = products;
  })
}
// ...
```

```html
<!-- ... -->
  <ng-container *ngIf="products">
    <product-list [products]="products"></product-list>
  </ng-container>
<!-- ... -->
```

And on child `product-list`:

```js
// ...
@Input() products: IProduct[];
// ...
```

```html
<!-- ... -->
  <div *ngFor="let product of products">
    <product-card [product]="product">
  </div>
<!-- ... -->
```

And than I have each `product-card` show `product.image`.

The problem I'm facing is, when ever I land on this page, I'm able to view all products, but when I click on something on the page and than browser back to this page, the product-list is not displayed.

I don't have any errors in console and I can confirm that the child component is receiving the data on the second render adding debug points in debug console.

Why is my child component only displayed on first render? Not even refresh will work.
Only when I navigate to the page by entering the url in browser will I get the same component to display. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really confused on what `this.products$` is in:  `this.store.select(this.products$)` If it's an observable, I'm surprised it's working. It should be a selector.

Comment: @Richard.Davenport I wrote my example wrong. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, my top component did not implement `OnDestroy` and the component was lingering after redirect. I solved the problem by doing the following:

```js
@Component({ /* ... */ })
class topComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  // ...
  private readonly destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

  // ...
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
}
```

The `destroy$.[METHOD]` will let go of any subscribed observables that you have subscribed by using `this.[SELECT].pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(...)`. Pretty neat.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You can also use take(1) if you know that you won't update the Product-store within the component

Comment: @SalminSkenderovic Yes, depending on the situation, this is a much better approach as there is no need to create a multicast observable as I have. Good one.

Answer (score 0):

ngInit is not being called on navigation back. Use ActivatedRoute and subscribe to params:

```
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
  route.params.subscribe(x => {

  });
}
```

use combineLatest if you want to to subscribe to both.
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest

Comment: "ngInit is not being called on navigation back". Are you sure about this? I'm pretty positive it is.

Comment: @tinnick sorry for the late reply. If you put a console.log inside your subscriber. Does it trigger every time?

Comment: Yes it does. And I figured what my problem is :)